# Android Studio:Evey time I test run my app to phone for debug,The Android Studio token a app-release.apk file which is not exist really

Tags: android, android-studio

Every time I run my project to my android phone, the Android Studio will show the info bellow,and also it will take a lot of time, but when I Revealing Finder,there not real generated newer app-release.apk file.

```html
下午3:46:16 Executing tasks: [:app:assembleRelease]
下午3:51:31 Gradle build finished with 3 warnings(s) in 5m 15s 4ms
下午3:51:32 Generate Signed APK
          APK(s) generated successfully.
          Reveal in Finder
下午3:51:32 Build APK
          APK(s) generated successfully.
          Reveal in Finder
下午3:51:32 Build APK
          APK(s) generated successfully.
          Reveal in Finder
下午3:51:32 Generate Signed APK
          APK(s) generated successfully.
          Reveal in Finder
下午3:51:32 Generate Signed APK
          APK(s) generated successfully.
          Reveal in Finder
下午3:51:32 Generate Signed APK
          APK(s) generated successfully.
          Reveal in Finder
下午3:51:32 Generate Signed APK
          APK(s) generated successfully.
          Reveal in Finder
下午3:51:32 Generate Signed APK
          APK(s) generated successfully.
          Reveal in Finder
下午3:51:32 Generate Signed APK
          APK(s) generated successfully.
          Reveal in Finder
下午3:51:33 Generate Signed APK
          APK(s) generated successfully.
          Reveal in Finder
下午3:58:04 Executing tasks: [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
下午4:02:27 Gradle build finished with 3 warnings(s) in 4m 23s 639ms
下午4:02:28 Generate Signed APK
          APK(s) generated successfully.
          Reveal in Finder
下午4:02:28 Build APK
          APK(s) generated successfully.
          Reveal in Finder
下午4:02:28 Build APK
          APK(s) generated successfully.
          Reveal in Finder
下午4:02:28 Generate Signed APK
          APK(s) generated successfully.
          Reveal in Finder
下午4:02:28 Generate Signed APK
          APK(s) generated successfully.
          Reveal in Finder
下午4:02:28 Generate Signed APK
          APK(s) generated successfully.
          Reveal in Finder
下午4:02:28 Generate Signed APK
          APK(s) generated successfully.
          Reveal in Finder
下午4:02:28 Generate Signed APK
          APK(s) generated successfully.
          Reveal in Finder
下午4:02:28 Generate Signed APK
          APK(s) generated successfully.
          Reveal in Finder
下午4:02:28 Generate Signed APK
          APK(s) generated successfully.
          Reveal in Finder
```

1. By the way: I am a newer in stackoverflow, because of “China's national firewall”,i lag behind,and thanks for everyone helped me.
2. Also, my last question was use pictures to describe my issue,now it let me lost some reputation, can I delete the bad question? If yes, how?
3. Thanks God let me know stackoverflow.

Comment: Welcome to SO from China man! In Android Studio you can have different Build Variants. Try to change it from release to debug.

Comment: Thanks @Murat K, I tested your method, it worked for me.U solved my issue, thanks.  And how can I give you repulation

Comment: It's fine. Don't need them.

Comment: @Murat K. By the way, how can I delete my answer? and  how to delete my question which is not good question?